# Moving MVC from Dev to Prod causes Parse Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, parse-error

In moving my MVC app from dev to prod, I get a parse error on the server.  The only message I get is the following:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TYPE of View Model>'.
        Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TYPE of View Model>" %>
        Line 2:  
        Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    Source File:  /Views/Workout/Index.aspx    Line:  1
```

I know this isn't very descriptive by any means, but it's all I have.  I have successfully deployed to this server before -- and as the great saying goes "it works on my machine"

A very odd thing is:  For pages that require a login, it manages to pull the login page.  Once you try to login or go to a page other than the login page, is when it throws the parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.5x1llz.com/index.php/cutting-teeth-on-mvc-could-not-load-type-system-web-mvc-viewpage/).  Turns out that somewhere in there I was missing a piece of information from my web.config under the pages directive.

It was a version issue such that I started the project with a beta version of MVC and have since upgraded to MVC RC 1.0 (it was NOT a MVC version issue from development machine to production server).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the version of sytem.web.mvc on your local machine and the deployment target are different?

Comment: I've deployed a previous version of my app with the same MVC version, so I'm leaning towards saying 'no' to a different version issue